# MapField not working on Blackberry device 9320

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have developed a blackberry app that uses a mapField. On the simulator the map field displays the map image of somewhere in canada and gets the coordinates. When i come to test this on a device I get a blank white screen but the long and lat coordinates do update. I dont seem to have a 'maps' app on the device and when i try to download the blackberry maps app i get told me software is not compatible

Im using a Blackberry 9320, firmware 7.1.0 Platform 9.49.

Is the mapfield out of date?

Comment: Which OS are you developing for? There's an `ExtendedMapField` class in 6.0, which is an enhanced version of `MapField` introduced in 5.0. Also note that the BG image for an area is downloaded by the field in BG, and it is cached for future use. So make sure you have connectivity (if over Wi-Fi, it takes some time to load).